# A SCNSphere with a SKScene texture renders only on a quarter of the sphere

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

So I have a SceneKit sphere object:

```
let mySphere = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)
let ballNode = SCNNode(geometry: mySphere)
```

to which I add a SpriteKit scene as texture:

```
someNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: textureAtlas.textureNames[0])
someNode.size = CGSize(width:1500, height:1500)
someNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

let scene2 = SKScene(size: someNode.size)
scene2.addChild(someNode)

ballNode.geometry!.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = scene2
```

That texture renders on one quarter of the sphere only:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: Try mapping that scene onto a plane before you try it on a sphere, and try reducing the size and changing the position of `someNode` — a little bit of experimentation there should make the way forward clearer.

Comment: How do I map a scene onto a plane?

Comment: Use SCNPlane instead of SCNSphere.

Answer (score 0):

It's helped me:

```swift
let textureImage = UIImage(named: "texture")!
let skScene = SKScene(size: textureImage.size)
let texture = SKTexture(image: textureImage)
let spriteNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)

spriteNode.position = CGPoint(x: textureImage.size.width / 2, y: textureImage.size.height / 2)
spriteNode.zRotation = Transforms.degreesToRadians(180).cgFloat()
spriteNode.xScale *= -1
```